# jq json parser hash the field value

Tags: parsing, hash, jq

I have a JSON file as the below:

```
[{
  "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
  "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:2a",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
  "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:3a",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}]
```

use `jq` to hash the `macAddress` field like so:

```
jq .[] | hash(.macAddress)
```

Can I define my own hash function and let `jq` to run the hash during the parsing process?

My expected hash function can be simple as using native linux command `md5sum`

```
echo -n "my_salt""42:12:20:2e:2b:ca" | md5sum
d973ea7c353e78ba1724efbc8054dfdc -
```

So the output json will be

```
[{
  "macAddress": "d973ea7c353e78ba1724efbc8054dfdc",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
  "macAddress": "d973ea7c353e78ba1724efbc8054d2er",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
  "macAddress": "d973ea7c353e78ba2324efbc8054d123",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}]
```

Comment: What would you want the output to be: a) a list of hashed mac addresses, separated by line feeds, or b) a JSON object like the input just with the mac addresses replaced with their hashed values, or c) something else? Please provide sample output in the question.

Comment: @HansZ. I have updated the requirements as per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My expected hash function can be simple as using native linux command **md5sum**

This stays native and might be suitable;

### Invocation :

```
jq -c .[] "$jsonfile" |
while read -r jsonline ; do
  hashmac="$(jq --arg mysalt "$mysalt" -s -j '
        .[] | "\($mysalt)" + .macAddress' <<<"$jsonline" |
      md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
  jq --arg hashmac "$hashmac" -s -r '
      .[] | .macAddress |= "\($hashmac)"' <<<"$jsonline"
done
```

---

### Example file - /tmp/testfile:

```
[{
  "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
  "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:2a",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
  "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:3a",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
 "macAddress": "42:12:20:2e:2b:ca",
 "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}]
```

### Result Output:

```
{
  "macAddress": "1f960fe4d24684ca44e5e67b6259362c",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}
{
  "macAddress": "3527422754ecbfdd01d48b17fce87842",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}
{
  "macAddress": "9bc8da72324448c3032a20fb67a31466",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}
{
  "macAddress": "d973ea7c353e78ba1724efbc8054dfdc",
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

### Comments:

- `-j` causes jq to not output a newline, equivalent to your `echo -n` example
- Variables in this example are sent to `jq` as strings using `-arg`, and referenced as `"\($var)"` **as opposed to** escaping the variable directly, for example:

  - `"\($mysalt)" + .macAddress'` (jq variable)

    Instead of:
  - `"'"$mysalt"'" + .macAddress'` (direct shell substitution)
- This example uses `cut -d ' ' -f1` to trim off the `-`, but there's probably a better way

### Alternate:

`jq --arg hashmac "$hashmac" -s -r '.[]  |= . + {"hashAddress":"\($hashmac)"}'`

Would append the json

```
[
  {
    "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a",
    "ip": "1.2.3.4",
    "hashAddress": "1f960fe4d24684ca44e5e67b6259362c"
  }
]
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer entails 2n + 1 invocations of jq, where n is the number invocations of the message digest function.

To reduce the number of invocations to just 2, see [shell-out value to md5 (crypto) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548580/shell-out-value-to-md5-crypto-function)