# How to update a value within an object with its md5 using jq?

Tags: json, jq, md5

Suppose I have the following JSON document (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739648/9002073))

**Initial document**

```json
{
  "key": "value",
  "ips": [
    {
      "ip": "1.2.3.4",
      "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a"
    },
    {
      "ip": "5.6.7.8",
      "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:2a"
    },
    {
      "ip": "9.10.11.12",
      "macAddress": "ac:5f:3e:87:d7:3a"
    },
    {
      "ip": "13.14.15.16",
      "macAddress": "42:12:20:2e:2b:ca"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to read every `macAddress` pass it to a hash function (e.g. `md5sum`) and write the result back to the JSON document.

**Desired output**

```json
{
  "key": "value",
  "ips": [
    {
      "ip": "1.2.3.4",
      "macAddress": "45ee585278a0717c642ff2cb25a8e441"
    },
    {
      "ip": "5.6.7.8",
      "macAddress": "ab47bf90cb9f385127977569e676ce70"
    },
    {
      "ip": "9.10.11.12",
      "macAddress": "a5e9785db428e3956a47776dbd00fc91"
    },
    {
      "ip": "13.14.15.16",
      "macAddress": "f75d61937f70252ff139adee241daab4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I've the following shell script, but I think it can be done more elegantly...preferably in a one-liner.

```bash
json_doc="{\"key\": \"value\", \"ips\": [{\"ip\":\"1.2.3.4\",\"macAddress\":\"ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a\"},{\"ip\":\"5.6.7.8\",\"macAddress\":\"ac:5f:3e:87:d7:2a\"},{\"ip\":\"9.10.11.12\",\"macAddress\":\"ac:5f:3e:87:d7:3a\"},{\"ip\":\"13.14.15.16\",\"macAddress\":\"42:12:20:2e:2b:ca\"}]}"

ip_list=$(jq -c '.ips[]' <<< "$json_doc" |
while read -r jsonline ; do
  hashmac="$(jq -s -j '.[] | .macAddress' <<<"$jsonline" | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
  jq --arg hashmac "$hashmac" -s -r '.[] | .macAddress |= "\($hashmac)"' <<<"$jsonline"
done | jq -s)

# Update json document with ip list containing hashed mac addresses
jq --argjson ips "$ip_list" '.ips = $ips' <<<"$json_doc"
```

Comment: Does this post help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48548580/5291015 or my own answer in Unix.SE - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/587410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of peak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552825/5291015) from the linked question. Two invocations of `jq`, first for calculating the md5 hashes and then re-construct the calculated result back into the original JSON using `reduce`

```bash
jq -r '.ips[].macAddress' input.json |
while read -r line ; do printf '%s' "$line" | md5 ; done |
jq -s -R --slurpfile json input.json 'split("\n")
  | map(select(length>0))
  | . as $in
  | reduce range(0;length) as $i ($json; .[].ips[$i].macAddress = $in[$i])'
```

The second `jq` invocation should be read carefully. The initial arguments `-s -R` are for reading the multi-line non JSON output created by the for-loop into jq's context. While the `--slurpfile` argument is needed for updating back the calculated hash into the original JSON. The slurp action takes the whole file into memory.

So as such this command, might not be effective for really large JSON files.

Comment: Great, this solves my problem. To get the desired output I've changed the last line to `| reduce range(0;length) as $i ($json[]; .ips[$i].macAddress = $in[$i])'`. This removes the array from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use `jq` to decompose the JSON into lines of scalars, then filter for and process relevant lines outside of `jq`, and eventually reassemble that stream with a second call to `jq`.

Here's one example using `jq`'s stream representation for the broken-down interstage, i.e. `jq -c . --stream` for the decomposition, and `jq -n 'fromstream(inputs)'` for the reassembly, and `awk` for the actual processing, as it can easily read and filter by lines, alter parts of it, and shell out to perform external tasks. To filter for lines like `[["ips",0,"macAddress"],"ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a"]` while waving through others like `[["ips",0,"ip"],"1.2.3.4"]` or `[["ips",0,"macAddress"]]`, a simple approach could be to interpret each line as columns separated by double quotes `"`, then filter for columns 2 and 4 matching a given content, and column 6 not being empty (which could obviously improved for robustness; this is just an example), then replace column 6 (using `getline`) with the output of `printf %s` on the 6th column's value, followed by your `md5sum` and `cut` processing. (Tested with [onetrueawk/awk](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk) version 20231124, and [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) 5.3.0.)

```bash
jq -c . --stream input.json | awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\"" }
  $2 == "ips" && $4 == "macAddress" && $6 {
    "printf %s " $6 " | md5sum | cut -d \\  -f1" | getline $6
  }
  1
' | jq -n 'fromstream(inputs)'
```

Here's another, more robust example that "manually" decomposes the input into value and path, while also appending a flag to mark the scalars that need to be further processed (queried by the `jq` path expression `.ips[].macAddress`), into lines like `"1.2.3.4" ["ips",0,"ip"] false` or `"ac:5f:3e:87:d7:1a" ["ips",0,"macAddress"] true`. The processing part of this example then only utilizes POSIX-compliant shell features like `read` to iterate through the lines, a `case` statement to deflect based on that flag, and `tr` and parameter expansion to extract the IP (which is assumed to not contain spaces or escapes). The final `jq` composer then collects the lines using `reduce`, and successively builds up the output using `setpath`.

```bash
jq -r '
  [ path(.ips[].macAddress) ] as $q
  | paths(type | IN("object","array") | not) as $p
  | @json "\(getpath($p)) \($p) \(IN($p;$q[]))"
' input.json |

while read -r line; do case "$line" in
  *false) printf '%s\n' "$line" ;;
  *true) printf '"%s" %s\n' "$(printf '%s' "${line%% *}" | tr -d '"' |
         md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f1)" "${line#* }" ;;
esac; done |

jq -s 'reduce _nwise(3) as [$v,$p] (null; setpath($p;$v))'
```

For the given input, both examples output

```json
{
  "key": "value",
  "ips": [
    {
      "ip": "1.2.3.4",
      "macAddress": "45ee585278a0717c642ff2cb25a8e441"
    },
    {
      "ip": "5.6.7.8",
      "macAddress": "ab47bf90cb9f385127977569e676ce70"
    },
    {
      "ip": "9.10.11.12",
      "macAddress": "a5e9785db428e3956a47776dbd00fc91"
    },
    {
      "ip": "13.14.15.16",
      "macAddress": "f75d61937f70252ff139adee241daab4"
    }
  ]
}
```